# .NET test Linux code depend on Environment.OSVersion.Platform on Windows

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unix, .net-core

I have a .NET Core cross-platform C# console app.

I have a code that depend on the OS, for example:

```cs
public int Foo(){
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Unix)
        return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

How can I write unit test that will run on **Windows**, and validate that when the code will run in **Linux**, it will return `-1`?

**How to fake the `Environment.OSVersion.Platform`?**

(Is there a reason I could not use ShimsContext?)

Comment: You could have a `IPlatformService` where the default implementation of `Platform` is to return `Environment.OSVersion.Platform`, and have a implementation for your tests which returns what you want.

Comment: You can from cmd.exe >Set which will give all the environmental variable that are used on a windows machine.

Comment: @jdweng OK, but which environment variable in Linux gives value to the Environment.OSVersion.Platform

Comment: @stuartd Are you talking about dependency injection?

Comment: Test for null so in windows the variable will return a value and in linux it will be null.

Comment: `Environment.OSVersion.Platform` really does not have anything to do with environment variables.